# how to avoid drawing of graph through inset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a figure which requires an inset. Using pdfplots i am nearly there but have the main graph plotting through the inset.

[image: mainandinset]

How can i avoid the drawing through the inset? Also is it possible to move the x/y-labels of the inset closer to their respective axes?

A copy of the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% Setting graphing environment
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{document}

% declare inset:
\newsavebox\inset

\begin{tikzpicture} []

    % declare constants:
    \pgfmathsetmacro\omega{1}

    % declare equations:
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{rho}{2}{\pgfmathparse{% density
        sin(deg(2*pi*#1))*cos(deg(2*pi*#2))*exp(-\omega*#2)}}

    % make plot for inset:
    \savebox\inset{
        \begin{axis} [ tiny, 
            domain=0:2, samples=50,
            xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=-1, ymax=1, no markers,
            xlabel=dimensionless time\, /\, $\theta$,
            ylabel=peak density\, /\, $\rho$,
        ]
        \addplot [] {rho(0.25,x)};
        \end{axis}
    }

    \begin{axis} [
        domain=0:1, samples=50,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1, no markers,
        xlabel=dimensionless coordinate\, /\, $x$,
        ylabel=dimensionless density\, /\, $\rho$,
        clip=false
    ]
        \addplot [] {rho(x,0)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $0$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,0.5)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $0.5$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,1)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $1$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,1.5)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $1.5$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,2)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $2$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,2.5)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $2.5$};

    \end{axis}

    \node [anchor=north east] at (4.3,3.7) {\usebox\inset};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For moving the axis labels closer to the axis, you can use `xlabel shift` and `ylabel shift` keys. To make room for the inset you can extend the range of the outer plot in the y axis, for example up to 2.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% Setting graphing environment
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{document}

% declare inset:
\newsavebox\inset

\begin{tikzpicture} []

    % declare constants:
    \pgfmathsetmacro\omega{1}

    % declare equations:
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{rho}{2}{\pgfmathparse{% density
        sin(deg(2*pi*#1))*cos(deg(2*pi*#2))*exp(-\omega*#2)}}

    % make plot for inset:
    \savebox\inset{
        \begin{axis} [tiny,
            domain=0:2, samples=50,
            xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=-1, ymax=1, no markers,
            xlabel=dimensionless time\, /\, $\theta$,
            xlabel shift = -1ex,
            ylabel=peak density\, /\, $\rho$,
            ylabel shift = -1.4ex,
        ]
        \addplot [] {rho(0.25,x)};
        \end{axis}
    }

    \begin{axis} [
        domain=0:1, samples=50,
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=2, no markers,
        xlabel=dimensionless coordinate\, /\, $x$,
        ylabel=dimensionless density\, /\, $\rho$,
        clip=false
    ]
        \addplot [] {rho(x,0)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $0$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,0.5)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $0.5$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,1)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $1$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,1.5)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $1.5$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,2)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $2$};
        \addplot [] {rho(x,2.5)} [yshift=-6pt] node [pos=0.25] {\footnotesize $2.5$};

    \end{axis}

    \node [anchor=north east] at (4.3,3.7) {\usebox\inset};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Also, you may want to reduce the `ymax` for the outer plot and use the option `axis background/.style={fill=white}` (or other color, if you prefer) for the inset, so that it "hides" the lines of the main plot which are drawn behind it. For example, the following figure was produced with `ymax=1.4`.

[image: Result2]

Comment: Or draw the main graph in the background layer.

Comment: @ajeh The main graph is indeed in the "background" in the sense that it is drawn before the inset, and thus the inset is drawn on top of the main graph. Adding `\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}` around the main graph does not change the result, unless you set also a white fill for the inset graph (I tested it).